# Rails 3 multiple accounts authentication solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, openid, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I am searching for a working solution of authentication on Rails 3 with the following features:

- account types: standard login, facebook connect, openid, oauth
- one user may have (and link) multiple accounts (EG a user attach both Wordpress and Google OpenID accounts)

A working example of Rails app implementing them would be perfect.

Comment: Vlad,  any update on what you find out?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) even thought it doesn't have every feature that you're asking for. But then again I doubt there's something out there doing all that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/socialite is hoping to be what you're looking for.